# When will elementary OS get Linux Kernel 4.10?

Tags: kernel, amd

when will elementary OS get kernel 4.10 as part of the default installation?

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all likely that 0.4 loki gets kernel 4.10 as the default kernel. However, you can install it via

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge
```

Comment: This is not recommended, it does not allow for upgrading various dependent packages in the same way. See https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11958/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-update-from-elementary-os-loki-0-4-to-loki-0-4-1

Answer (score 0):

I am running Linux 4.11.0 and 4.10.15 on my eOS Loki. I am using a customized kernel made by Xanmod. You can visit his webpage here: https://xanmod.org/