# What is the recommended way to update from elementary OS Loki 0.4 to Loki 0.4.1?

Tags: release-loki, updates

Now that elementary OS Loki Update 1 (0.4.1) has been released, how can I upgrade to it without reinstalling?

Comment: I have the same problem. I did a dist-upgrade under elementary 0.4.1 and now I have the 4.10.0-28 kernel at work.
I have several graphic problems. How to do a clean rollback of that dist-upgrade to kernel 4.8-x like before the dist-upgrade? Its my computer at work and it needs a hardreboot every 1h since dist-upgrade. I would appreciate your answer a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Step 1. Update

1. Open up `AppCentre`
2. Navigate to the `Updates` tab
3. Install all available updates
4. Reboot if required

Now your `System Settings > About` section should look like the following image. Note that it states "elementary OS **0.4.1** Loki", not 0.4.

[image: elementary OS 0.4.1]

## Step 2. Upgrade Kernel [Optional]

While your system now runs the latest version of elementary OS, it may not be running the latest kernel underneath. If you experience no problems with your hardware, this upgrade may only create minor performance imporvements. However, if your brightness or wireless was unsupported, this may fix some of your problems.

**This is dangerous. You should create a backup before proceeding.**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends \
    linux-generic-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 \
    xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04
```

Once this is complete and you have rebooted, you should see `Linux 4.8.*` in the elementary section of the `About` settings panel, instead of 4.4.*

Comment: What is AppCenter? All I see is Software Center. And there is no tab for Updates. Could you please elaborate, if possible?

Comment: If you look in System Settings > About, are you sure you're running 0.4? AppCenter was not available until then, so if you're using Freya (0.3) you would need to follow different instructions.